# Firebase child_added + limit() + transaction() behaving unexpectedly

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase

I have a worker queue that waits for items and processes them as they come in. Here is a simplified version that creates 3 pieces of work and processes them:

```
firebaseRef = '_fiddle1';
data = new Firebase('https://fiddles.firebaseIO.com/HQyac/' + firebaseRef + '/data');
workers = new Firebase('https://fiddles.firebaseIO.com/HQyac/' + firebaseRef + '/workers');

// clear all data
data.remove();
workers.remove();

// listen for new work
workers.limit(1).on('child_added', function (snapshot) {
    var workerName = snapshot.name();
    var workerVal = snapshot.val();
    console.log('INVOKED: ', workerVal + ' [' + workerName + ']');

    // increment counter as example work
    data.child(workerVal).transaction(function (tran) {
        return tran + 1;
    }, function (error, committed, snapshot2) {
        console.log('COMMITTED: ', snapshot2.name() + ' = ' + snapshot2.val() + ' [' + workerName + ']');
        workers.child(workerName).remove();
    }, false);
});

// create work
workers.push('WORKER1');
workers.push('WORKER2');
workers.push('WORKER3');
```

Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/thinkloop/HQyac/) of the same code. If you run it, however, work is performed 4 times, rather than the expected 3 times, with 'WORKER2' always being processed twice (see console). If you [open the firebase](https://fiddles.firebaseio.com/HQyac) you can see the same.

There is a simple fix/workaround for this: simply omit "limit(1)" from the work listener:

```
workers.on('child_added', function (snapshot) {
```

If you run it with that modification, workers run 3 times as expected.

Is this a bug?

Comment: I don't understand the point of the limit here. If you're removing the workers as they get processed, limit shouldn't be necessary. However, I can confirm the behavior you're seeing with the transactions and that is a bit perplexing.

Comment: I want to process the oldest/first item whenever any item gets added. If the queue is running slow, and item #5 gets added, I still want to process item #1 next. In my real code I have a startAt() next to the limit(), but it does not affect the "bug" so I left it out.

Comment: Actually, I'm not even sure what limit (1) is supposed to do with "child_added", I was just trying it out when I found this "bug". 

Is it supposed to watch the whole list and return the first or last item depending on whether startAt/endAt are used? Or is it supposed to only watch the one spot for something added?

The one "advantage" with limit(1) instead of just a pure "on" is that it does not load the whole collection on start up.

Comment: I did this experiment just a week ago but I'm already a bit hazy; I think limit alone returns the first record in the path (which is probably meaningless without priorities and startAt/endAt). If you add startAt/endAt, then it is called each time a new record arrives.